# WPF Listview backgroundcolor for 1 colomn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, background

Hello everybody and thank you for reading this ,

I have a WPF app for a HotelSystem , im showing the taken / reserved rooms in a listview that has some room properties like room nr,type, isReserved and so on.
I am able to change the color of the rows if the room isReseved == true , but i want only that column "IsReserved" is changed not the entire rows and i didn't find any answers and after trying some things in XAML , here i am.

XAML code :

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReserved}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

[My User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHfLt.png)

Thanks for your time !

Kind Regards

Comment: You can bind you background color to some property in your data source and before fill the listview check for reservation and change the property value if it reserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mention column, I guess you are saying that the `ListView` has a `GridView` as a View.

In that case, rather than change the style for `ListViewItem`, you need to look at you columns declaration, find the Column in your `XAML` that you want to effect, then change the `Column.CellTemplate` like this:

```
<Column.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid x:Name="Container">
      ......
      </Grid>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsReserved}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" TargetName="Container" />
         </DataTrigger>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
   </DataTemplate>
</Column.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: No it hasn't , sorry for my uncorrect terminology ,i thought a column was the name for the red rectangle in my UI picture. im not that expereinced in XAML ,its just a ListView with no grid or anything else in it.   @Eins , how would i do that , isReserved is a bool ,i don't know how to bind a color to that property.Thank you guys for the really fast replies !

Comment: Hello and sorry for the delay i am busy working on my dissertation, i have tryed other ways but this was actually exactly what i wanted , i didn't had a gridview in it so i implemented one . @Eins i wanna thank you to because with your answer i implemented a feature with it (binded a png to aproperty) to display in the listview. So thank you both !Kind regards